# How do I add a boolean column to an existing table to indicate if there's a matching id value for each row in another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a table, `foo`

```
id
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

and another table `bar`

```
id product
 1     abc
 1     def
 4     ghi
 4     abc
```

I want to add a boolean field, *has_product* to `foo` that indicates whether it has at least one record in `bar` with a matching *id*. In this example,

```
id has_product
 1        true
 2       false
 3       false
 4        true
```

How can I do this?

---

### Reproducible Example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.foo AS

(
  SELECT 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS id
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.bar AS

(
  SELECT 1 AS id, "abc" as product
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS id, "def" as product
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS id, "ghi" as product
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS id, "abc" as product
);
```

---

### What I've tried

I suspect there's a combination of [`ADD COLUMN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_column_statement) and [`UPDATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) that will do the trick. For example, the below code inserts a column with all true values.

```
alter table test.foo add column has_product bool;

update test.foo
set has_product = True
where true
```

**result**

```
id has_product
 1        true
 2        true
 3        true
 4        true
```

(But obviously this is not my desired result.)

Comment: I wish the person who downvoted this question would provide constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure below works efficiently for your real situation, at least it will return what you expect for small sized toy data. Hope this is helpful.

```sql
alter table test.foo add column has_product boolean;

update test.foo
   set has_product = EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test.bar WHERE bar.id = foo.id)
where true;

select * from test.foo;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *view* this particular output, you may use a left anti-join:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT f.id, b.id IS NOT NULL AS has_product
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN bar b
    ON b.id = f.id
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to update the table itself (for performance and cost reasons)

Comment: ...what happens when new data gets added?  Would you have to keep running this update?

Comment: `foo` is recreated daily, and its ids may change every day. `bar` is created daily, immediately after `foo`, and is partially dependent upon `foo`.

Comment: The `has_product` column is _derived_ data, and therefore your requirement might work better as a view rather than an update.

Comment: My table is quite large and gets queried many times per day. I've set a partition on the table to improve the performance and cost of those queries. Wouldn't a view hurt performance and costs?